# Unable to resolve "react-navigation-drawer" from "App.js"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

Mine react-navigation drawer is not working, I am getting this error while running the app, any suggestion to fix this problem.

`Unable to resolve "react-navigation-drawer" from "App.js"`

```
import React from 'react';

import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import {createDrawerNavigator} from 'react-navigation-drawer';
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native';

import {Feather} from 'expo/vector-icons'
import { ProfileScreen, MessageScreen, ActivityScreen, ListScreen, ReportScreen, StatisticsScreen, SignoutScreen} from './screens';

const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  ProfileScreen,
  MessageScreen,
  ActivityScreen,
  ListScreen,
  ReportScreen,
  StatisticsScreen,
  SignoutScreen
})

export default createAppContainer(DrawerNavigator);
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't installed `react-navigation-drawer` in your project and you are trying to use it.

run `yarn add react-navigation-drawer` inside your project directory then it should work.